# Convert timestamp (int) to smalldatetime (t-sql)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, timestamp, smalldatetime

I have a **MySQL**-Database with several rows. In that environment, I stored the current time as a Timestamp (`int`).

Now I need to migrate my data from a MySQL to a T-SQL-Database. I'm running **SQL-Server 2008**.

I checked several approaches, but couldn't come up with a way which transforms my int into a **smalldatetime** format.

Is there a build-in function for this? Is this even doable alone in a statement? I really don't want to write a PHP-snippet, which converts the timestamp to the desired format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql), `smalldatetime` uses the following format:

```
DECLARE @smalldatetime smalldatetime = '1955-12-13 12:43:10';
```

So, we need to convert the `MySQL` timestamp into `date` and format it in the above format to get `smalldatetime`. This can be done by using `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `DATE_FORMAT` functions of `MySQL`, e.g.:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column), '%e %b %Y') AS 'smalldatetime';
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9deb/78/0)**.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME is only available in MySQL not T-SQL.